# Given a non-regular measure, working with a regular one, and going back.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm trying to show the following.

> **Proposition.** Let $T$ be the unit circle in the complex plane. Let $\mu$ be a complex Borel measure on $T$. Define the sequence $\hat\mu$ by
> $$ \hat\mu(n) := \int e^{-int} \  d\mu(t) $$
> for each $n\in\mathbb Z$. If $\hat\mu(n) \to 0$ as $n\to +\infty$, then
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int e^{-int} f(t) \ d\mu(t) = 0 $$
> for every bounded Borel-measurable function $f$ on $T$.

(Reference: RCA by W. Rudin, Exercise 6.7)

**What I have done.** I have proved that the conclusion of the proposition holds if $f$ is continuous. And I think it is now enough to check the case of characteristic functions on Borel sets. Lusin's theorem provides a connection between continuous functions and measurable functions, but it requires the measure to be regular, which is not guaranteed right now.

So I rely on Riesz representation theorem. The linear functional on $C(T)$, defined by
$$ f \mapsto \int f \ d\mu $$
is bounded since
$$ \left| \int f \ d\mu \right| \le \|f\|_\infty \cdot \|\mu\| $$
and $\mu$ is of BV, being a complex measure. So I get a unique complex regular Borel measure $\phi$ such that
$$ \int f \ d\phi = \int f\ d\mu $$
for every continuous $f$.

Now we may use Lusin's theorem. Let $E$ be a Borel set in $T$ and $\epsilon>0$. Then we get a continuous function $f$ such that $|\phi|(S) < \epsilon$ for $S := \{ t: f(t) - \chi_E(t) \ne 0 \}$ and $\|f\|_\infty \le 1$. Then
$$ \left| \int e^{-int} f(t) \ d\phi (t) - \int e^{-int} \chi_E(t) \ d\phi (t) \right| \le \int_S |f-\chi_E|\ d|\phi| \le \int_S (\|f\|_\infty + \|\chi_E\|_\infty)\ d|\phi| \le 2\epsilon. $$
Using this inequality, it is easy to show that
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int e^{-int} \chi_E(t) \ d\phi(t) = 0. $$
But how to restore the measure to $\mu$? This is my question.

Comment: $\phi -\mu$ is a  complex Borel measure and $\int f d(\phi-\mu)=0$ for every continuous $f$ implies that $\phi=\mu$. In fact any complex Borel measure $\mu$ on $T$ is regular and there is no need to introduce $\phi$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can I find a proof for that?

Comment: It is proved in Rudin's book that any positive Borel measure on a sigma compact locally compact space finite on compact sets is regular. Since a complex measure is a linear combination of finite positive measures the result follows.